# sql query preference order

Tags: sql, select, preference

I am struggling with this query. I have a table deliverystatus with two fields, Email and Status. This table is populated with emails and their associated delivery statuses such as "enroute", "delivered", "no status", "undelivered". For a given email their can always be a status of "enroute" in addition to any other statuses mentioned. If an email has a status of "enroute" and no other statuses then only "enroute" should be selected, any other status should always supersede "enroute" and should be the only one reported. Check out the table below.

```
|Email       | Status      |
|----------  | ------------|
|abc@abc.com | enroute     |
|abc@abc.com | delivered   |
|xyz@abc.com | delivered   |
|jkl@abc.com | undelivered |
|ppp@abc.com | enroute     |
```

When I do this query, it should only get me the following. Notice abc@abc.com was only reported once with the "delivered" status as it superseded "enroute", whereas ppp@abc.com was listed with "enroute" since there was no other status found for that email.

```
|Email       | Status      |
|----------  | ------------|
|abc@abc.com | delivered   |
|xyz@abc.com | delivered   |
|jkl@abc.com | undelivered |
|ppp@abc.com | enroute     |
```

can anybody assist please?

Comment: There should be a timestamp field in the table, or at least some kind of sequence number.

Comment: Is the problem really that you want to show each email only once with its highest precedence status? Or does the table need to be unique by email & status so there is only one row to pick? Or, as wildplasser says, it needs a timestamp and only pick the latest entry per email?

Comment: Using the CASE expression, you could assign a value to each of the expected status values, in the order of preference that you want, and then use max() and GROUP BY email to achieve your requirements.

Comment: Yes, there is a timestamp value in the table like this. 2021-12-17 17:42:18.093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're dealing with no more than two status values and you're already using `group by`:

```
coalesce(max(case when status <> 'enroute' then status end), 'enroute')
```

Or

```
coalesce(max(nullif(status, 'enroute')), 'enroute')
```